# How can sort ancient greek words using XSLT?

Tags: xslt, sorting, unicode, diacritics

I just spent too long trying to find out how to conveniently sort Ancient Greek using XSLT and saxon, so I am asking this question here so that others can read the answer, which I will post in a moment.

When sorting classical Greek, diacritics are usually ignored.

However, there is more than one way of representing accented Greek letters in unicode.

The following code therefore first normalizes the Greek grouping key I want to sort on to non-precomposed characters and then deletes the diacritics for the purposes of sorting:

```
<xsl:sort select="translate(normalize-unicode(current-grouping-key(), 'NFD'), 
&#x0300;&#x0301;&#x0304;&#x0306;&#x0313;&#x0313;&#x0300;&#x0313;&#x0300;&#x0345;&#x0313;
&#x0301;&#x0313;&#x0301;&#x0345;&#x0313;&#x0342;&#x0313;&#x0342;&#x0345;&#x0313;&#x0345;
&#x0314;&#x0314;&#x0300;&#x0314;&#x0300;&#x0345;&#x0314;&#x0301;&#x0314;&#x0301;&#x0345;
&#x0314;&#x0342;&#x0314;&#x0342;&#x0345;&#x0314;&#x0345;&#x0345;', '')"/>
```

This was not clear from the start, however, and I am posting this here hoping people will find this helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
<xsl:sort select="..." collation="http://saxon.sf.net/collation?ignore-modifiers=yes"/>
```

See http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensibility/collation.xml

Comment: Thanks. NO, I didn't find the documentation or did not understand or recognize it. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Collations require XSLT 2.0; they are also to a considerable extent implementation-dependent.